Empty plot and no error given
By the advise of Jagra, I removed the first set of the code and leave the actual problem. I  got a working script, but the plot is empty. I tried to run it in chrome and firefox, but to no difference.
What is the reason when plots are "empty" and no error is given?
(* Define parameters *)
L = 10;                 (* Length of the domain *)
T = 15;                 (* Total time *)
dx = 0.08;              (* Spatial step size *)
dt = 0.001;             (* Time step size *)
xValues = Range[-L/2, L/2, dx]; (* Spatial grid *)
mMax = Round[T/dt];     (* Maximum time index *)

(* Ma-soliton initial condition *)
A = 1; (* Amplitude *)
c = 0.5; (* Velocity *)
k = 1; (* Wave number *)
\[Psi]0[x_, t_] := A Sech[x - c t] Exp[I (k x - (c^2 + k^2) t)];

(* Initialize wave function *)
\[Psi] = Table[\[Psi]0[x, 0], {x, xValues}];

(* Time evolution function *)
timeEvolution[\[Psi]_, m_] := Module[{\[Psi]New, nonlinearTerm},
    \[Psi]New = \[Psi];  (* Start with the current wave function *)
    (* Update wave function using FDM *)
    For[i = 2, i < Length[\[Psi]] - 1, i++,
        nonlinearTerm = Abs[\[Psi][[i]]]^2 \[Psi][[i]];
        \[Psi]New[[i]] = \[Psi][[i]] - (dt/(2 I)) ((\[Psi][[i + 1]] - 2 \[Psi][[i]] + \[Psi][[i - 1]])/(dx^2)) - dt nonlinearTerm;
    ];
    \[Psi]New
];

(* Store results for animation *)
results = {};
(* Time-stepping loop *)
For[m = 1, m <= mMax, m++,
    \[Psi] = timeEvolution[\[Psi], m];
    If[Mod[m, Round[mMax/5]] == 0, AppendTo[results, \[Psi]]];  (* Store every 5th wave function *)
];

(* Create the animation *)
ListAnimate[Table[
  ListLinePlot[results[[m]], PlotRange -> All, 
               PlotLabel -> "Ma-Soliton Evolution", 
               AxesLabel -> {"x", "\[Psi](x,t)"}, 
               PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}, 
               ImageSize -> Large,
               PlotLegends -> {"t = " <> ToString[m dt]}],
  {m, 1, Length[results]}
]]


Consider replacing the For[] loops with a more functional construct.

The code supplied appears to have an undefined function: HyperbolicSech[]

Unless you think it adds anything, I suggest that you remove your first set of code.

The first solution below addressed an earlier state of the OP's original.
The second, provides I think a slightly clearer way to do what the OP, now wants that they didn't previously describe.
First solution
(*Define parameters*)
L = 10;                 (*Length of the domain*)
T = 15;                 (*Total time*)
dx = 0.08;              (*Spatial step size*)
dt = 0.001;             (*Time step size*)
xValues = Range[-L/2, L/2, dx]; (*Spatial grid*)
mMax = Round[T/dt];       (*Maximum time index*)

(*Ma-soliton initial condition*)
A = 1; (*Amplitude*)
c = 0.5; (*Velocity*)
k = 1; (*Wave number*)
\[Psi]0[x_, t_] := A*Sech[x - c t]*Exp[I *(k x - (c^2 + k^2)* t)];

(*Initialize wave function*)
\[Psi] = Table[\[Psi]0[x, 0], {x, xValues}];

(*Time evolution function*)
timeEvolution[\[Psi]_, m_] := Module[{\[Psi]New, nonlinearTerm},
   \[Psi]New = \[Psi];(*Start with the current wave \
function*)(*Update wave function using FDM*)
   For[i = 2, i < Length[\[Psi]] - 1, i++,
    nonlinearTerm = Abs[\[Psi][[i]]]^2*\[Psi][[i]];
    \[Psi]New[[i]] = \[Psi][[i]] - (dt/(2 I)) ((\[Psi][[i + 1]] - 
           2 \[Psi][[i]] + \[Psi][[i - 1]])/(dx^2)) - 
      dt *nonlinearTerm;];
   \[Psi]New];

(*Store results for animation*)
results = {};
(*Time-stepping loop*)
For[m = 1, m <= mMax, m++, \[Psi] = timeEvolution[\[Psi], m];
  If[Mod[m, Round[mMax/5]] == 0, 
   AppendTo[results, \[Psi]]];  (*Store every 5th wave function*)];

(*Create the animation*)
ListAnimate[
 Table[
  ComplexListPlot[results[[m]],
   PlotRange -> All,
   PlotLabel -> "Ma-Soliton Evolution",
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "\[Psi](x,t)"},
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue},
   ImageSize -> Large,
   PlotLegends -> {"t = " <> ToString[m dt]}], {m, 1, 
   Length[results]}]]


Your results has complex numbers and would therefore need something like ComplexListPlot.
I also suggest, using Times explicitly rather than proximity.
Second solution
This solution places the calculation results in a Module which generates the real values of Psi.  This will make it easier to refactor this code in the future, perhaps replacing the For loop with a functional solution.
Now having the list of reals, you can remove the Re[] from ListLinePlot.  This separates calculations from plotting making it easier to refactor (improve) code going forward.
(*Define parameters*)L = 10;                 (*Length of the domain*)
T = 15;                 (*Total time*)
dx = 0.08;              (*Spatial step size*)
dt = 0.001;             (*Time step size*)
xValues = Range[-L/2, L/2, dx]; (*Spatial grid*)
mMax = Round[T/dt];     (*Maximum time index*)

(*Ma-soliton initial condition*)
A = 1; (*Amplitude*)
c = 0.5; (*Velocity*)
k = 1; (*Wave number*)
\[Psi]0[x_, t_] := A Sech[x - c t] Exp[I (k x - (c^2 + k^2) t)];

(*Initialize wave function*)
\[Psi] = Table[\[Psi]0[x, 0], {x, xValues}];

(*Time evolution function*)
timeEvolution[\[Psi]_, m_] := 
  Module[{\[Psi]New, 
    nonlinearTerm}, \[Psi]New = \[Psi];(*Start with the current wave \
function*)(*Update wave function using FDM*)
   For[i = 2, i < Length[\[Psi]] - 1, i++, 
    nonlinearTerm = Abs[\[Psi][[i]]]^2 \[Psi][[i]];
    \[Psi]New[[i]] = \[Psi][[i]] - (dt/(2 I)) ((\[Psi][[i + 1]] - 
           2 \[Psi][[i]] + \[Psi][[i - 1]])/(dx^2)) - 
      dt nonlinearTerm;];
   \[Psi]New];

(*Store results for animation*)
results = Module[{r},
   r = {};
   (*Time-stepping loop*)
   For[m = 1, m <= mMax, m++, \[Psi] = timeEvolution[\[Psi], m];
    If[Mod[m, Round[mMax/5]] == 0, 
     AppendTo[r, \[Psi]]];  (*Store every 5th wave function*)];
   Re[results]];

(*Create the animation for the real part of the wave function*)
ListAnimate[
 Table[ListLinePlot[results[[m]], PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLabel -> "Ma-Soliton Evolution (Real Part)", 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "Re[\[Psi](x,t)]"}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}, 
   ImageSize -> Large, PlotLegends -> {"t = " <> ToString[m dt]}], {m,
    1, Length[results]}]]



We shouldn't comment that out, because that is the initial condition.

Your original code hasn't provided a definition of A HyperbolicSech[].  As such it doesn't seem to make sense in your function \[Psi]0[x_] :=, which looks like it might more properly read as, \[Psi]0[x_] :=(*A HyperbolicSech[x]*)   Exp[I k x] + perturbationAmplitude Sin[2 Pi x/5]

I realized you intend A to multiple your HyperbolicSech[].

It should plot the real part of psi.

Actually, as you have now described it, you want to plot the real part of your list results.  Your original post used an undefined function HyperbolicSech[].  Your revision attempted to plot complex numbers.  Hard to help when what you need keeps changing.

I changed because you invited me to do so

Here is what I got fixed, now it looks correct:
(* Define parameters *)
L = 10;                 (* Length of the domain *)
T = 15;                 (* Total time *)
dx = 0.08;              (* Spatial step size *)
dt = 0.001;             (* Time step size *)
xValues = Range[-L/2, L/2, dx]; (* Spatial grid *)
mMax = Round[T/dt];     (* Maximum time index *)

(* Ma-soliton initial condition *)
A = 1; (* Amplitude *)
c = 0.5; (* Velocity *)
k = 1; (* Wave number *)
\[Psi]0[x_, t_] := A Sech[x - c t] Exp[I (k x - (c^2 + k^2) t)];

(* Initialize wave function *)
\[Psi] = Table[\[Psi]0[x, 0], {x, xValues}];

(* Time evolution function *)
timeEvolution[\[Psi]_, m_] := Module[{\[Psi]New, nonlinearTerm},
    \[Psi]New = \[Psi];  (* Start with the current wave function *)
    (* Update wave function using FDM *)
    For[i = 2, i < Length[\[Psi]] - 1, i++,
        nonlinearTerm = Abs[\[Psi][[i]]]^2 \[Psi][[i]];
        \[Psi]New[[i]] = \[Psi][[i]] - (dt/(2 I)) ((\[Psi][[i + 1]] - 2 \[Psi][[i]] + \[Psi][[i - 1]])/(dx^2)) - dt nonlinearTerm;
    ];
    \[Psi]New
];

(* Store results for animation *)
results = {};
(* Time-stepping loop *)
For[m = 1, m <= mMax, m++,
    \[Psi] = timeEvolution[\[Psi], m];
    If[Mod[m, Round[mMax/5]] == 0, AppendTo[results, \[Psi]]];  (* Store every 5th wave function *)
];

(* Create the animation for the real part of the wave function *)
ListAnimate[Table[
  ListLinePlot[Re[results[[m]]], PlotRange -> All, 
               PlotLabel -> "Ma-Soliton Evolution (Real Part)", 
               AxesLabel -> {"x", "Re[\[Psi](x,t)]"}, 
               PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}, 
               ImageSize -> Large,
               PlotLegends -> {"t = " <> ToString[m dt]}],
  {m, 1, Length[results]}
]]


